# advantages of Roslyn vs ReSharper

Tags: resharper, roslyn

When I created project in VS2015 Roslyn is added by default, and I am also using Resharper in my project so can anyone help me to understand any advantages of Roslyn vs Re-sharper

Answer (score 5):

Roslyn is CaaS (Compiler as a service) and *enables* several features in VisualStudio and additional extensions that can be installed. ReSharper doesn't use Roslyn, but has its own model for code analysis that already serves for over a decade.

Here is a comparison matrix:
https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/comparisonMatrix_R2017_1_vs2017.html

Answer (score 3):

Roslyn is the C# compiler and the default C# IDE features. You cannot have a C# project without Roslyn. Resharper adds more C# IDE features (some of these overlap with the default).